# How to initialize a ASP.NET User Control With parameter?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, ascx

For example, I have a user control(ascx) with a label inside,
I will use the the user control in my aspx page.

How can I pass a string value to the ascx page so that it can be display in the label of ascx page at the beginning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this...

```
public string Whatever
{
get { return label.Text; }
set { label.Text = value; }
}
```

to your ascx control.  Then from the page you are putting it in you can just set the text like... `usercontrol.Whatever = "text to display";`

or you can use the Whatever as a property on the aspx side of the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can expose whatever controls you want access to in your user control by creating property for them.

In the past when I have had user controls that required certain data for setup I would create an Initialize method which would take in and setup whatever was needed.